# How to neutralize bleach in a washing machine

Tags: organic-chemistry

i’ve seen a couple threads on this website about neutralizing bleach but none of them really say how to do it.

for some context, someone put 7 cups of bleach in our washing machine along with the water without any clothes inside because they wanted to disinfect the washing machine from a specific pathogen. They talked to Clorox on the phone and they said it was okay to use more bleach but now they’re double backing and saying that you weren’t supposed to use more than half a cup.

i’ve done multiple rinse cycles sense in order to wash away any residue but were nervous that because it was so much bleach that the cycles aren’t effective or that we need to do more and will never know exactly when it’s OK to use again.

So I just want to nip it in the bud and neutralize whatever residue that’s in there. I’ve seen people say to use Hydrogen peroxide but I  obviously don’t want to cause any accidents if there are residue in there. I’ve seen a different product but I don’t know if it’s safe to use in the washing machine or how much to use to neutralize 7 cups of bleach.

This experience has been extremely stressful, I don’t want clothing to have residue bleach on it and possibly put  pets and people in danger.

*** addition from og post*** I’ve read online that vinegar is not a good one i don’t know if that because of the possible reaction or because it’s not a neutralizer. Also does any one know of a way to test for residue?

Any advice would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide does *not* neutralize bleach. Since the machine is fairly-well cleaned out by now, a half-cup of vinegar should eliminate any bleach left. If the vinegar smell lingers, give one more rinse, empty. BTW, that much bleach may have *greatly* shortened life of some parts of the washer -- expect repairs to be needed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik everywhere i look people are saying to use peroxide to neutralize the bleach which i found weird because of the possible reaction of it. I’ve put it to do a heavy load four times almost everyday since so i figure it’s okay now but since it’s so much we’re terrified of it

Comment: putting vinegar in the washing machine also doesn’t make me feel good. Won’t it cause a reaction?

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide is another bleaching agent. It makes no sense at all to use it to destroy Clorox. Clorox is highly water soluble, the multiple rinse cycles you have run will have washed it out.

Comment: i don’t care about the machine. I’ll deal with the damage what i care about is to make sure there isn’t any residue inside so the people and pets that will sleep and use what we wash in there will be safe from bleach effects. Especially because we use HP in the wash and i don’t want to risk a reaction

Comment: @KarstenTheis I’m confused by the sentence  “following the rinse is recommended for disinfecting with zero. 5 cups of bleach”. What do you mean by that

Comment: @DrMoishePippik By neutralisation, they might not mean acid-base-wise, but in broader sense redox-wise, hypochlorite oxidizing peroxide to oxygen.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Oh i see, i just want to make sure there isn’t any left over reside in there but are a little lost on how to do that

Comment: Easy way and test is - washing it away ( perhaps after rough/course elimination by chosen method) by empty water cycles, until smell of intentionally left residual chlorine is gone. This way you have a sensitive feedback. If you let it fully react with something, there would be possibly corrosive components and you would not have the feedback if you washed them away - what you have to do either way.

Comment: I agree with the idea of an empty wash cycle. Bleach (Sodium hypochlorite) is very soluble in water and fairly reactive, so it should be easy to wash away into the sewer with an empty cycle (or two if needed).

Comment: One issue I've had with bleach used in a cleaning cycle is that agitation is more *vigorous* without laundry, splashing bleach into areas not effectively rinsed. The next load sometimes has bleached spots on items. A bit of vinegar might be helpful after massive overuse of bleach... or not.

Comment: @Poutnik i’m a bit confused by your comment, are you saying the best way to test is to see if it smells like bleach? or are you saying i should use the elimination method and then do more empty cycles and see if it smells? When i said is there a test i was thinking like PH paper or idolize paper etc

Comment: @DrMoishePippik my washer does not have a agitation or a bleach dispenser. See my issue isnt left over bleach it’s any residue that left from applying it. Like how it leaves a residue when you use it on a table etc. that residue can then be harmful to you or others. I want to get rid of the residue not leftover

Comment: @JeffGustafson I’ve done several empty cycles. So im wondering you said if needed, how would you know if it’s needed? Since you can’t see the residue

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide _does_ in fact neutralize chlorine bleaches, because it reacts with the active bleaching spcecies (hypochlorite) to make oxygen gas, water, and chloride ions.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0011916498000344

Comment: @CurtF. i thought so, clorox says to neutralize bleach with it but it’s seems to say that for clothing not to clean up on other material